# Vue isn't update DOM when data comes from ajax

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to add some data to my view from ajax response. I'm looking in devTools and it looks like I have all data changed, but in the view it displays like empty values.

JS file:

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    versions: [
        {
            name: 'A'
        },
        {
            name: 'B'
        },
        {
            name: 'C'
        }
    ]
},
beforeCreate: function () {
    var self = this;

    axios.get('http://serviceUrl.com')
        .then(function (response) {
            self.parseResponse(response.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.warn(error);
        });

},
methods: {
    addDataToVersion: function (version, propertyName, value) {
        this.versions.forEach(function (element) {
            if (element.name === version) {
                element[propertyName] = value;
            }
        });
    },
    parseResponse: function (data) {
        for (let key in data) {
            let tag = key.split('.')[0];
            let version = key.toString().split('.')[1];
            let quantity = data[key];

            this.addDataToVersion(version, tag, quantity);
        }
    }
}});
```

This is my html code snippet. `version.name` is displaying good, but all data which come from ajax (`version.VIEW, version.CLICK`) is not displaying. I see it in inspector in right place in data object, So I'm sure it's here

```html
<div class="columns">
        <div v-for="version in versions" class="column is-one-third">
            <div class="version-column">
                <div class="tags has-addons">
                    <span class="tag">Version</span>
                    <span class="tag is-primary">{{ version.name }}</span>
                </div>
                <p><span class="has-text-weight-semibold">Views:</span> {{ version.VIEW }}</p>
                <p><span class="has-text-weight-semibold">Conversions:</span> {{ version.CLICK }}</p>
                <p><span class="has-text-weight-semibold">CR:</span> 100%</p>
             </div>
         </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [this.$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) to avoid reactivity problem.

```
   addDataToVersion: function (version, propertyName, value) {
       var vm = this;
        this.versions.forEach(function (element,index) {
            if (element.name === version) {
                vm.$set(`versions[${index}]`,propertyName, value);
            }
        });
    }
```

It would be better if you can read through https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#ad to learn why your problem occurred.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! It doesn't work like that for me, I did like this `vm.$set(vm.versions[index], propertyName, value);` and it works perfect. Thanks for fix and for reference.